# call function inside class and use the result in another function

Tags: python, function, class

```
class myclass():
    def fun(self):
        a = 12
        return a

    b = fun()

TypeError: fun() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

The idea is to be able to use `b` inside another `def`, like

```
class myclass():
    def fun(self):
        a = 1
        return a

    b = fun()

    def fun2(self):
        c = self.b + 2
```

Is this possible?

Comment: `def fun2(self): c = self.fun() + 2`?  or is the idea that you want to make sure to only call `fun` once?

Comment: I don't understand why you even need `b` here?

Answer (score 0):

Since `myclass.fun` is an instance method, if you want to cache its result you should do that in an instance attribute (defined in `__init__`) rather than a class attribute.

```
class myclass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = self.fun()

    def fun(self):
        a = 1
        return a

    def fun2(self):
        c = self.b + 2
```